# Как провернуть SQL инъекцию на простом коде?

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, товарищи.

Я вот чет встал в тупик, как можно на этом коде провернуть SQL инъекцию? Ваши мысли по этому поводу. Буду очень признателен. )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Для доступа к Бобруйской районной библиотеке введите Ваши учётные данные:</h2>
<form method="get" action="?">
    <p>Введите ваше имя</p>
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <p>Введите ваш пароль</p>
    <input name="password" type="text"><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "1111", "db_library");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
    $mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
    $mysqli->query("SET character_set_client = UTF8");
    $mysqli->query("SET character_set_connection = UTF8");
    $mysqli->query("SET character_set_results = UTF8");
}

$name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'password');
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name = '$name' AND password = '$password'")) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo "<p><b>Ваше имя: </b> $obj->name</p>
        <p><b>Ваш статус:</b> $obj->status</p>
        <p><b>Доступные для Вас книги:</b> $obj->books</p><hr />";
    }
} else {
    printf("Ошибка: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
$mysqli->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что необходимо сделать : отправить в инпуте данные, содержащие кавычку. Например, пароль' OR 1--

"--" в MySQL - комментарий, то есть мы комментируем все последующие действия, и наш запрос обретает вид:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name = '$name' AND password = 'пароль' OR 1'"
```

В данном случае мы получим данные всех пользователей из данной таблицы